Why are both operating systems showing up on the same drive during dual boot?
I have been working on adding Ubuntu to my PC for ROS2. I added a Samsung 990 to my computer so I could install it to a separate SSD.
I first did the "Try Ubuntu", and ran lsblk --nvme. This told me that nvme0n1 was the old Samsung 970 (which I have windows on), and nvme1n1 is Samsung 990, the new empty drive.
I tried installing Ubuntu with "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" and specified nvme1n1, however after it was completed, the BIOS showed that Ubuntu was on 970, and the windows boot was gone.
So then I tried a flash drive bootable windows install, and specified Disk 1. This seems to have worked correctly; I can launch both Windows or Ubuntu from the BIOS.
However, my one problem is that in the BIOS, under Boot Priority, it says...

Windows Boot Manager (M.2_3: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1 TB)
Ubuntu (M.2_3: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1 TB)

AKA that they are both on 970, even though in GParted, it seems to show all the Microsoft stuff/ntfs is on nvme1 (see the image below). Additionally, when GRUB first opens before Linux, there is no option to launch windows, I have to launch it from BIOS.
GParted shows that ubuntu is on nvme0 and windows is on nvme1:

Does anyone know what has caused the inconsistency between my install and what the BIOS is showing? Thanks!

Ah, ok. When I run that, it is showing that /boot/efi is on nvme0n1p1 (a partition on the 970). I didn't realize that when the BIOS says "M.2_3: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1 TB", it's justing saying that this is where the ESP/the boot files are, but not necessarily where OS itself is. Thanks!

@mook765, one last thing... based on that Gparted image I added, does there seem to be any glaring issues with how I set up dual boot? I'm wondering if I did something wrong because GRUB isn't showing windows, or if that might just be because Windows is in hibernation/fast boot. Thanks again

I don't have the reputation to upvote your comment, but if you make in an answer Ill mark it correct.

It's not an inconsitency, it's only the boot loader which has been installed into the already existing ESP (EFI System Partition).
You can check with the terminal comand lsblk -f in Ubuntu which partitions are used for your /- partition and the ESP.
If grub doesn't show Windows in the grub menu, Windows hybernation may be the cause. It may also caused by grub configuration, you may need to add the line
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

to /etc/default/grub and run sudo update-grub after doing so.
But before doing so, just run sudo update-grub and look at it's output, it will tell you exactly if grub is checking for other operating systems or not.
Here an example from my system:
~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for mook: 
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sdc4
Found Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (24.04) on /dev/sdc5
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
done


Running sudo update-grub fixed the problem, Windows Boot Manager is on GRUB now. Thanks mook!
